# RecordsAffected count from query not working with Sharepoint

Tags: vba, ms-access, append

I have an append query which takes records from a temp table and adds them to another table. I put in these lines to display the no. of records added:

```
Dim RCount As Long
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Append_to_Dataset")
qdf.Execute
RCount = qdf.RecordsAffected
```

This worked fine when the tables were local, but then I converted the tables to be on Sharepoint. The append still works, but RCount always reports zero.

Does RecordsAffected not work with Sharepoint? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Try defining a database instance e.g. `Dim db as Database` 
`Set db = CurrentDb`
`db.querydefs...etc etc`

Comment: Tried this, same result unfortunately.